# Существуют ли способы динамического создания уникальных страниц (адресов) для контента из БД?

Tags: html, php, view

Вопрос в следующем.
Есть БД с новостями. На данный момент вывод одной новости осуществляется путем запроса к БД из страницы news.php?view=new&id=20, черпая необходимую инфу из адресной строки.
Суть вопроса: как сделать так, чтобы новость открывалась по уникальному адресу (=на уникальной странице). Возможно ли этот процесс сделать автоматическим без размножения действительно существующих уникальных страниц? То есть так, чтобы необходимая страница создавалась автоматически при запросе в адресной строке. 
У меня есть решение следующее: при добавлении новости создается новая страница и линк на нее хранится в базе. Но верно ли это? Ведь новостей может быть много, очень много...

Comment: База для того и база чтобы там хранилась информация, много -- очень много. Смысл в следующем, когда подключается контроллер news ( = урл вида: www.site.com/news/sometimes-russian-student/ ) ищется в базе "sometimes-russian-student" и выдается нужный контент.

Comment: для новостей ключом является дата + тема. /2014/02/14/s-dnem-sv-valentina/
храните транслит темы и дату, htacess'ом преобразуете url...

Comment: ЧПУ наверное вам надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под фразой "уникальная страница", но предположу, что это страница с адресом типа www.site.ru/news/horoshaya_novost.html  (такие адреса называют термином человекопонятный УРЛ (ЧПУ)). Сами УРЛ хранятся в БД вместе с страницей. Пользователь перейдя по ссылке такого вида заставляет скрипт искать запись в базе с таким УРЛ, и если она найдена, формируется страница с новостью. Для этого как правило используют mod_rewrite и файл .htaccess, например перенаправляем все запросы на index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

После этого анализируем введеный пользователем адрес ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] и формируем по нему страницу

Comment: большое спасибо. направление ровно то, какое и искал.